# On a User page, reputation tab what does the first column (reputation) represent

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

I thought this colum represented the total rep received on the question, but apparently not always.  For example, John T has [two votes on some question](https://superuser.com/questions/42543/45406#45406), plus an acceptance.  The associated rep on his user page at the time I wrote this was indicates the rep is [570](https://superuser.com/users/1931?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top).

Is there a rule that would allow 10 + 10 + 15 = 570?

This result is not consistent with [previous answers posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/numbers-in-the-rep-tab)

How is this possible?  And no, I'm not envious, just curious.  OK, maybe a bit envious ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there was a bounty on that question, which explains the spike in rep awarded to the accepted answerer.

Comment: Ah, I see the question mark shows it had a 550 bounty. So it turns out it's 570 instead of 585 due to some other reputation limiting thing happening?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you don't get the 15 for an accepted answer if there is a bounty?